# Algorithm correctness

Tags: algorithm, analysis, pseudocode

I'm studying loop invariants at the moment and I have trouble with my choiche for an invariant for a linear search algorithm.

```
Inpput: A[1 ... n] of integers, k an integer value
Output: true if k belongs to A[1 ... n] false otherwise

LSearch(A,k)
i := 1
found := false
 WHILE i<=n AND found=false DO
   IF A[i] = k THEN
     found := true
   i:=i+1
return found
```

The assertion which I choose is:

- *found contains true or false if k is present among A[1] and A[i]*

Before the first iteration it holds because at that time in A[1] is a single element and found is initialized to false.
After the loop i can be equal 
     i := 1
     found := falseto n and/or found can be true (while condition), so the assertion remain the same with the consideration of i<=n.
Do you think that this can be correct?

Comment: why not return TRUE when solution is found ?

Comment: The code is on my textbook. For your suggestion the invariant would be different, I think.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice "AND found=false" in the while-loop condition

Comment: How about "found is false iff k is not in the range A[0] to A[i]"

Answer (score -1):

The assertion is correct, but also useless. found is a boolean, and will contain True or False, irrespective of the properties of A. This won't help you prove the correctness of your algorithm.

Was this a multiple choice question? What were the other choices?

Comment: There are no other choices, I made the assertion. I used that and worked with inference rules to say that if the Assertion is true before and after the code the algorithm is correct. In the case found is false the range A[1] ... A[i] is respected as i=n(the loop ends cause of the while condition). If it is not sufficent what should I use as an invariant (the proprierties of A[] is not related to the boolean at all?)

Comment: @Daved: Try finding out the conditions when found is false.